# Conditionally attach HttpObjectAggregator in the Channel Pipeline

Tags: performance, netty

For some use cases, eg: when it is a `GET` request or a `WebSocket` upgrade request, the `HttpObjectAggregator` turns out to be performance overhead and can easily be omitted.

Can I conditionally add the `HttpObjectAggregator` by detecting if it is not a GET request or a websocket request?

**Update 1**

```
// on channelRead()

if (req.isInstanceOf[JFullHttpRequest]) {
    val aggregator = new JHttpObjectAggregator(Int.MaxValue)
    val pipeline   = ctx.channel().pipeline

    pipeline.addLast(OBJECT_AGGREGATOR, aggregator)

    // re-attaching the handler
    pipeline.remove(HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLER)
    pipeline.addLast(HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLER, this)

    // firing channel read again
    aggregator.channelRead(ctx, jHttpRequest)
}
```

I was able to make it work by adding the aggregator conditionally. Why do I need to re-attach the handler?

**Update 2**

```
// on channelRead()

if (req.isInstanceOf[JFullHttpRequest]) {
    val aggregator = new JHttpObjectAggregator(Int.MaxValue)
    val pipeline   = ctx.channel().pipeline

    pipeline.addBefore(HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLER, aggregator)    
}
```

This version actually worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can modify the `ChannelPipeline` on the fly.

Comment: wouldn't we missout on the initial few messages if the aggregator is added afterward?

Comment: I was able to make it work by doing two things — 1. perform a channelRead() on the aggregator once after adding it to the pipeline and then 2. removing and adding the sharable request handler again.

Comment: I am not sure why do I have to remove and add the handler again.